# Return 1 row with various sums based on date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume a table of purchase transactions with columns `CustId, Amount, DatePosted` where Amount is the value of the transaction, and DatePosted is a DATETIME value. Given a specific CustId, how would I write a select such that it returns a single row with the following columns: `CustId`, total value of transactions in the last 3 days, last 60 days, 1 year, 2 years (5 columns total).

Example table:

| CustId | Amount | DatePosted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 698.02 | 2023-01-23Z12:34:56 |
| 1234 | 582.69 | 2022-12-15Z19:57:23 |
| 1234 | 7775.22 | 2022-12-02Z02:34:32 |
| 1234 | 18.72 | 2022-01-23Z12:34:56 |
| 1234 | 2.27 | 2021-01-23Z12:34:56 |

Expected output given the sample data above when searching using CustId=1234:

| CustId | 3-day Total | 60-day Total | 1 year Total | 2 year Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 698.02 | 9055.93 | 9074.65 | 9076.92 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Together with DDL + DML commands, thank you

Comment: Please also show your best attempt

Comment: @learning I have no idea what either of those 2 are, but I attached some sample data  and expected output based on that data. The numbers are pretty random and not realistic, but hopefully they illustrate the point.

Comment: SELECT CustId, SUM(CASE WHEN DatePo >= @param1 AND

Comment: SELECT CustId, SUM(CASE WHEN @@param1 <= DatePo AND DatePo <= @@param2 THEN Money END) /*End of SUM Call*/, etcc FROM Blaaa WHERE Filter GROUP BY CustId

Answer (score 1):

You could get all purchase data for the last 2 years, then using SUM with [SQL CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to calculate total value for each time-range.

```
SELECT 
  CustId, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= Last3Day THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [3-day Total],
  SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= Last60Day THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [60-day Total],
  SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= Last1Year THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [1 year Total],
  SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= Last2Year THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [2 year Total]
FROM 
  <your data table>,
  (SELECT 
      DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) AS Last3Day,
      DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE()) AS Last60Day,
      DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) AS Last1Year,
      DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) AS Last2Year) timerange
WHERE DatePosted >= Last2Year      
GROUP BY CustId;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/179880

Answer (score 1):

This query assumes 2 year max. If you want to go further back then change the where clause as well. No need to use coalesce or a derived table. SQL server query planner may be smart enough to provide similar performance for all these solutions but this is easier to understand:

```
SELECT 
    CustId, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [3-day Total], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [60-day Total], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePosted >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [1 year Total], 
    SUM(Amount) AS [2 year Total]
FROM PurchaseTransactions
WHERE CustId = 1234 AND DatePosted >= DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE())
GROUP BY CustId
```

Comment: If you use the where clause as you do, the last of the four sums doesn't need any case when.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Ah, you're right. I went ahead and changed. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

This is set up so that you can set @CustID = null and the query will return results for all customers in the set.

EDIT: Updated my query below to give you more flexibility across your desired ranges should you wish to derive additional heuristics. (Counts, averages, etc.)
Also removed coalesce as it's simply not needed here.

```
DECLARE @CustID BIGINT;

SELECT table1.custID,
    SUM([3Day].amount) AS [3DayTotal],
    COUNT([3Day].amount) AS [3DayCount]
    SUM([60Day].amount) AS [60DayTotal],
    SUM([1Year].amount) AS [1YearTotal],
    Sum([2Year].amount) AS [2YearTotal],
    AVG([2Year].amount) AS [2YearAverage]
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT custID, Amount FROM table1 WHERE DatePosted > DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())) AS [3Day] ON table1.CustID = [3Day].CustID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT custID, Amount FROM table1 WHERE DatePosted > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())) AS [60Day] ON table1.CustID = [60Day].CustID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT custID, Amount FROM table1 WHERE DatePosted > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) AS [1Year] ON table1.CustID = [1Year].CustID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT custID, Amount FROM table1 WHERE DatePosted > DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) AS [2Year] ON table1.CustID = [2Year].CustID
WHERE table1.CustID = @CustID 
    OR @CustID IS NULL
GROUP BY table1.CustID
```